# Reducing the prominence of information on the UI

Tags: gui-design, hierarchy, wearables

I'm redesigning the UI for an industrial smartwatch face, the challenge I'm facing is one of the complications 'Active Hours' needs to be less prominent. Not all their users are required to use it anymore. However, it still needs to be present on the watch face as some users are still required to use it. Asking developers to design 2 versions is not an option.

From these 2 versions, which would make the 'active hours' less prominent, while still keeping it visible?

Option A - I'm taking a 'Hidden in plain sight' approach by placing it near something substantially more prominent.

Option B - placing it below the rest would make it less prominent

[image]

Would like to know your thoughts and which is the better option. Thanks

Comment: ...curious, what percentage of users need to see active hours?

Comment: From my perspective, immediately after the most prominent element is not at all "hidden in plain sight", but rather elevated in priority. So, B.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles lets say about 30%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple eye scan heatmaps to demonstrate how large features draw the eye to it and on to adjacent elements:

[image: heatmap 1][image: heatmap 2]

The second image source article, [*What Gets Lost in the Heat Map*](https://www.eyetracking.com/what-gets-lost-in-the-heat-map/), illustrates the point that images are easily interpretible, and therefore require less attention, are often scanned but don't get represented well in heatmap. In the watch interface presented in this question, the "10:09" at the top surely ranks early and high on the eye scan process but since it, like the images on the above example, is easily understandable the eye quickly moves on to the nearest element for further interpretation or more information.

Therefore option B, without the icon and color, will draw the least attention.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create a visual hierarchy of information display, and from the two designs above we can see the combination of the below elements come into effect:

- horizontal position
- font size
- colour
- iconography

Even though you mentioned that not all users still need to see the active hours reading, but those that need it might still want it to be prominently displayed. But if you are planning to put it at the lowest visual hierarchy, then you could try a combination of the following and do a quick eye test with other people in the team:

- change the colour to something less bright compared to the blue, green and red that have already been used
- changed the font size of the label to match the value displayed for active hours
- remove the icon in front of the value
- position it right at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

With your brief, I'd choose B, and simply adjust the active hour bar as below:

- Blue color of number looks a bit outstanding -> change to gray
- Remove icon of active hours row

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Active Hours should just be positioned at the bottom. The display is blocks of text so its vertical position matters

Also, I think using color this way might work better. Colored text can get really hard to read. Especially darker colors like blue on a black background. If you use white text on colored background both the text and the colors are easier to read

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Active Hours in option B is less prominent.

> Option A - I'm taking a 'Hidden in plain sight' approach by placing it
> near something substantially more prominent.

I'd argue that. Since the time element is much bigger than others, it grabs the eyes immediately and it's more likely that you pay attention to its adjacent object.

Also, as you mentioned in the comments that around 30% of users need the active hours, it's enough percentage to not make it less highlighted than others (e.g. by removing the icon or changing the color).